# Error while handling "NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest"

Tags: swift

When I execute the `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest` it always show the same error:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(NSURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(NSURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Void'"

This is the code:

```
    progressBar.hidden = false
    progressBar.progress = 0
    var am = Int(ammount * 100)
    var amToOwner = Int()
    let process = Float(100-fee)*Float(ammount)/Float(100)
    amToOwner = Int(self.roundToPlaces(0, number: process))
    progressBar.progress = 33.3
    let urlPath: String = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    request1.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var stringPost = String()
    stringPost="amount=\(am)&currency=eur&source=" + self.tok + "&description=\"\(description)\"&destination[account]=\(ownerAccountID!)&destination[amount]=\(try! Int(amToOwner*100))" // Key and Value
    stringPost = stringPost.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "")
    print(stringPost)

    let data = stringPost.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    request1.timeoutInterval = 60
    request1.HTTPBody=data
    request1.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request1.setValue("Bearer " + _secretKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request1.HTTPShouldHandleCookies=false
    print(request1.allHTTPHeaderFields)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in)
       self.progressBar.progress = 66.6
        self.tok = ""
        do {
            self.progressBar.progress = 100
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                print("ASynchronous\(jsonResult)")
                if jsonResult.valueForKey("error") != nil{
                    let alert = UIAlertController()
                    alert.title = "Error"
                    let callFunction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(callFunction)
                    alert.message = String(jsonResult.valueForKey("error")!.valueForKey("message")!)
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController()
                    let callFunction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(callFunction)
                    alert.title = jsonResult.valueForKey("outcome")!.valueForKey("seller_message")! as! String
                    var amm = jsonResult.valueForKey("amount")!.floatValue / 100
                    alert.message = "Ammount: \(amm) \(jsonResult.valueForKey("currency")!)\n Description: \(jsonResult.valueForKey("description")!)"
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    self.progressBar.hidden = true
                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            self.progressBar.progress = 100
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            self.progressBar.hidden = true
        }


    })
```

Whats the error? Could you help me?

I'm using XCode 7.3.1

Comment: You duplicated the error, yet because no markdown indicated anything, neither showed as the error. I eliminated both the duplication and added markdown to make it look like "error text".

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        self.progressBar.progress = 66.6
        self.tok = ""
            self.progressBar.progress = 100
            if let jsonResult = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                print("ASynchronous\(jsonResult)")
                if jsonResult!.valueForKey("error") != nil{
                    let alert = UIAlertController()
                    alert.title = "Error"
                    let callFunction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(callFunction)
                    alert.message = String(jsonResult!.valueForKey("error")!.valueForKey("message")!)
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController()
                    let callFunction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(callFunction)
                    alert.title = jsonResult!.valueForKey("outcome")!.valueForKey("seller_message")! as! String
                    var amm = jsonResult!.valueForKey("amount")!.floatValue / 100
                    alert.message = "Ammount: \(amm) \(jsonResult!.valueForKey("currency")!)\n Description: \(jsonResult!.valueForKey("description")!)"
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    self.progressBar.hidden = true
                }
        }
    })
```